# Lumen is not injecting a model into controller's method

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, lumen

I am trying to use Lumen's dependency injection for injecting a model's instance into a controller's method based on the model id passed as a parameter in the request URL. This works fine with Laravel. Very common in Laravel Resource controllers. Lumen using same service container as Laravel has been unable to do the job. Here is my request route:

`$router->get('post/{post}', "PostController@show");`

Here is the action method being called.

```
/**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show(Post $post)
        {
            //
            if($post)
            {
                return $this->response("Post found.", Response::HTTP_OK, $post->toArray());
            }
            return  $this->response("Post not found.", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

This is the exception message being thrown.

> App\Http\Controllers\PostController::show(): Argument #1 ($post) must be of type App\Models\Post, string given

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, you are either passing a string (instead of an int so it does not resolve) or you are trying to use something different than the `id` (unless your id is not integer but string) or you forgot to modify what column to use when using implicit binding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is how I call this URL https://exampledomain.com/post/1

Comment: I am starting to think that Lumen does not have Implicit Binding available. I used Lumen once but 4 years ago and I think I faced a similar "issue" (Lumen did not have `FormRequests`)

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for the response. Yeah, that can on be a possibility.